# Do comparable standards like FIPS exist for Germany or the European Union?

Tags: fips, nist

NIST, the National Institute of Standards and Technology, does publish FIPS, the Federal Information Processing Standards Publications.

Does Germany or the European Union have their own standards?

Or do comparable standards at all exist in the world?

FIPS Publications Examples below:

[image: Screenshot form nist.gov – 30.05.2022]

Screenshot from nist.gov – 30.05.2022

Comment: I googled "eu version of fips" and this was the top hit: https://www.enisa.europa.eu/publications/tsp1-framework/at_download/fullReport

Comment: Not exactly. The US philosophy is to define precise algorithms and architectures. For example, you must use AES, not Camellia, even though there's no reason to think Camellia is less secure. European agencies largely leave the definition of algorithms, protocols and architecture to private actors. What they want is a convincing argument that the product is secure (which is easier when it's “I used AES securely” than when it's “I rolled my own crypto”). Look up [SOG-IS](https://www.sogis.eu) publications and participating national agencies.